# Check how much GB time machine's backup need to be restored?

Tags: time-machine, backup, restore, disk-space

I have:

- Main: working copy of Mac OS X the capitan, in a 1TB hard drive,
- External: I have another external 1TB HD with the time machine copy,
- Next Main?: Empty **120GB** SSD HD

After deleting all the files I don't need, I have 138GB of used space in my main  HD,

I'm thinking of restoring the Time machine backup to the SSD

My question is,

How Can I  know for sure if the backup fits in my 120GB Disk?

PD: I know anyway that I need to delete, at least, 20GB more, but the question would come back then..

Comment: At least 10-15% of free space are recommended. So you would have to delete another 10 GB!

Comment: Thanks! I know, but I mean, to be able to restore it; I will care about perfomance once I restored successfully